# Delegate can see private items in calendar despite not having 'CanSeePrivateItems' flag

Tags: windows, powershell, outlook

We have a delegate to a user mailbox calendar. This delegate can see the details of the users meetings/appointments marked as private despite the user not having the 'Delegate can see my private items' box checked in the users Outlook client. When I run the Get-MailboxfolderPermission user.one@company.co.uk:\Calendar command in powershell the delegates 'SharingPermissionFlags' flag only lists Delegate and does not include 'CanViewPrivateItems'.

The delegate has editor access rights. I have tried completely removing the delegate from the users mailbox and mailbox calendar permissions, to the point that I had to add the delegate again in order to assign permissions.

I feel like i am missing something simple but i just want this delegate to NOT be able to see the users private appointments/meetings

Comment: The delegate can see the items in the calendar, or the delegate can see the items AND the _details_ of the items?

Comment: Hi Mathias, thanks for the quick response. The delegate can see the private appointment in the users calendar and can see the details of the appointment.

Answer (score 0):

test this setting to see if it helps

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\options\Calendar]
"RestUpdatesForCalendar"=dword:00000000

The problem is with the feature to turn on the MS 365 shared calendar improvements option in Outlook.